# Passing const char* variables to a function

Tags: c++

I'm having a weird and unexpected result in my code and I'd like your support to explain me what happens here.

I have a structure of a confiration :

```
struct sConfig {
  const char* ssid;
  const char* password;
}
```

I'm loading this configuration using LittleFS from a deserialized json :
config.ssid         = json["ssid"]; // so this is coming from the FS in a json file
config.password         = json["password"]; // so this is coming from the FS in a json file

So far, all is fine, I can print out the value using
`Serial.println(config.ssid);`

I'm then calling an internal void function

```
startWiFi(config.ssid, config.password);
void startWiFi(const char* ssid, const char* psswd) {
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(psswd);
}
```

As a result, the console returns :
`⸮`
and
`?:⸮?@⸮8⸮?<9⸮?⸮8⸮?:⸮?@⸮8⸮?<9⸮?⸮8⸮?:⸮?@⸮8⸮?<9⸮?⸮8⸮?.:⸮?@⸮`

What can be wrong in my variables ?
Please help me as I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Arduino Uno serial monitor printing garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53457467/10147399)

Comment: Looks like you are storing pointers to text data owned by `json` object. Does that object outlive `config`? My first guess would be that `json` goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving `config` with dangling pointers.

Comment: If I understood well, I can confirm the config structure as well as the json are defined at the beginning of the Arduino script. And the call to startWiFi function is inside the setup()

Comment: Can you show us the simplest code that can replicate the error? Can you replicate the error without the JSON library?

Comment: Consider using std::string or std::string_view.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I'd avoid copying a pointer and copy the actual data.
So, instead of `config.password = json["password"];`
I'd declare `ssid` and `password` as `char` arrays and copy the values from the json with `strncpy()`

```
struct sConfig {
    char ssid[32];
    char password[64];
}
```

or I'd allocate them on the spot with a custom copy function

```
char * myCopy (char *destination, const char *source)
{
    // I'm using 64 because is the max length of WPA2-PSK passwords
    size_t len = strnlen(destination, 64);
    destination = malloc((num + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(destination, source, num);

    return destination;
}
....
myCopy(config.ssid,     json["ssid"]);
myCopy(config.password, json["password"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening here is a use-after-free bug.

At `config.ssid = json["ssid"]` you copy a pointer to the internal memory of the json object. It's probably valid at the time of that copy (so the print succeeds), but when the json changes its state or gets deallocated, you get garbage at that memory address.

The solution is - as suggested in the other answer - copy the whole string and not just its address.